# Es posible hacer esto? funcion return

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def EnPartida(tablero_disparos,tablero_posicion,turno):

    global hundido1
    global hundido2
    global hundido

    if turno== True:
        print("Es tu turno.")
        tiro, hundido=disparo(tablero_disparos)
        hundido1= hundido1 + hundido
        if tiro== True:
            return tiro, hundido1;

    if turno== False or tiro== False:
        print("Es turno del rival.")
        tiro2, hundido=disparo(tablero_posicion)
        hundido2= hundido2 + hundido
        if tiro2== True:
            tiro2 = False
            return tiro2, hundido2;
```

Pregunto porque me tira error y creo que es porque no es posible hacerlo como yo quiero.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/Lucho/Desktop/Batalla Naval/Batalla Naval.py", line 109, in
>   
>       hundido1, turno = EnPartida(tablero_disparos,tablero_posicion,turno) TypeError: cannot
>   unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Si no explicas que quieres hacer y pones en contexto tu código va a ser difícil decirte si es o no posible o correcto lo que haces, no obstante ¿Que pasa si `tiro` o `turno` son `False` y `tiro2` es `False` también? en tal caso no retornarías nada explícitamente, lo cual significa que la función retorna `None` (retornno por defecto de cualquier función o método) y tienes el error mencionado...

Comment: Se necesita más código para comprender pero parece que usas una variable que no ha sido activada por el error, tal vez el error este en la función disparo y también creo que hay un error en tus if.

Comment: Para aclarar, el error es simplemente que llama a la función  `EnPartida` mediante `undido1, turno = EnPartida(tablero_disparos, tablero_posicion,turno)`, la función le retorna `None` porque no cae en ningún condicional (con esos argumentos `tiro` o `turno` son `False` y `tiro2` es `False` también) y por tanto no puede desempaquetar y asignar los valores a `undido1` y  `turno`. Realmente está intentando hacer `undido1, turno  =  None` . Esto debería contemplarse en la función, pero probablemente hay un fallo en la lógica o en los argumentos pasados que sin más contexto es imposible determinar.